# Are there a set of simple scripts to manipulate csv files available somewhere?

Tags: python, perl, csv

I am looking for a few scripts which would allow to manipulate generic csv files...

typically something like:

1. add-row  FILENAME INSERT_ROW
2. get-row  FILENAME GREP_ROW
3. replace-row  FILENAME GREP_ROW INSERT_ROW
4. delete-row FILENAME GREP_ROW

where

- FILENAME             the name of a csv file, with the first row containing headers, "" used to delimit strings which might contain ','
- GREP_ROW             a string of pairs field1=value1[,fieldN=valueN,...] used to identify a row based on its fields values in a csv file
- INSERT_ROW           a string of pairs field1=value1[,fieldN=valueN,...] used to replace(or add) the fields of a row.

peferably in python using the csv package... 
ideally leveraging python to associate each field as a variable and allowing more advanced GREP rules like fieldN > XYZ...

Answer (score 4):

Perl has a tradition of in-place editing derived from the unix philosophy.

We could for example write simple add-row-by-num.pl command as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi
BEGIN { $ln=shift; $line=shift; }
print "$line\n" if $ln==$.;
close ARGV if eof;
```

Replace the third line by `$_="$line\n" if $ln==$.;` to replace lines.  Eliminate the `$line=shift;` and replace the third line by `$_ = "" if $ln==$.;` to delete lines.

We could write a simple add-row-by-regex.pl command as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi
BEGIN { $regex=shift; $line=shift; }
print "$line\n" if /$regex/;
```

Or simply the perl command `perl -pi -e 'print "LINE\n" if /REGEX/'; FILES`.  Again, we may replace the `print $line` by `$_="$line\n"` or `$_ = ""` for replace or delete, respectively.

We do not need the `close ARGV if eof;` line anymore because we need not rest the `$.` counter after each file is processed.

Is there some reason the ordinary unix `grep` utility does not suffice?  Recall the regular expression `(PATERN){n}` matches `PATERN` exactly n times, i.e. `(\s*\S+\s*,){6}{\s*777\s*,)` demands a 777 in the 7th column.

There is even a perl regular expression to transform your `fieldN=value` pairs into this regular expression, although I'd use `split`, `map`, and `join` myself.

Btw, [File::Inplace](http://search.cpan.org/~chipt/File-Inplace-0.20/lib/File/Inplace.pm) provides inplace editing for file handles.

Comment: There is also a Text::CSV module if you need it.

Comment: the trick is that the field=value means that the header with the same name as field needs to have the same value...  for instance,  my first line of the csv might be: country,town,zip and my querry might be replace-row foo.csv "town=NewYork,country=us" "zip=10010" which would instruct to replace the content of the zip field of rows matching us,NewYork with 10010...

Comment: In that case, the begin line must build the regular expression, but maybe some CSV module can handle that for you more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Perl has the [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/DBD-CSV-0.33/lib/DBD/CSV.pm) driver, which lets you access a CSV file as if it were an SQL database.  I've played with it before, but haven't used it extensively, so I can't give a thorough review of it.  If your needs are simple enough, this may work well for you.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way in Python is to use the [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to load the data into a list of tuples, then do your add/replace/get/delete operations on that native python object, and then use [csv.writer](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write the file back out.

In-place operations on CSV files wouldn't make much sense anyway.  Since the records are not typically of fixed length, there is no easy way to insert, delete, or modify a record without moving all the other records at the same time.

That being said, Python's [fileinput module](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) has a mode for in-place file updates.

Answer (score 0):

[App::CCSV](http://p3rl.org/App%3a%3aCCSV) does some of that.